# SQL query for matrix results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data:

```
Key1 | Key2 | KValue
=====+======+=======
   A |    X |   100
   B |    Y |   200
   C |    X |   220
   B |    X |   300
   B |    Y |    50
```

I know in advance that `Key1` can have the following values `['A','B','C','D']` and `Key2` values `['X','Y']`.

I need the SQL which will return the matrix of all `Key1 x Key2` combinations with sum of their values (the combination with zero sum too). So the result from previous thata should return this:

```
Key1 | Key2 | KSUM
=====+======+======
   A |    X |  100
   A |    Y |    0
   B |    X |  300
   B |    Y |  250
   C |    X |  220
   C |    Y |    0
   D |    X |    0
   D |    Y |    0
```

`GROUP BY Key1,Key2` will not return zero sum rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with
     table1 ( key1 ) as (
       select 'A' from dual union all
       select 'B' from dual union all
       select 'C' from dual union all
       select 'D' from dual
     ),
     table2 ( key2 ) as (
       select 'X' from dual union all
       select 'Y' from dual
     ),
     test_data ( key1, key2, kvalue ) as (
       select 'A', 'X', 100 from dual union all
       select 'B', 'Y', 200 from dual union all
       select 'C', 'X', 220 from dual union all
       select 'B', 'X', 300 from dual union all
       select 'B', 'Y',  50 from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing purposes only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select t1.key1, t2.key2, nvl(ksum, 0) as ksum
from     table1 t1
         cross join
         table2 t2
         left join
         ( select   key1, key2, sum(kvalue) as ksum
           from     test_data
           group by key1, key2
         ) t3
              on t1.key1 = t3.key1 and t2.key2 = t3.key2
order by key1, key2
;
```

**Output**:

```
KEY1 KEY2 KSUM
---- ---- ----
A    X     100
A    Y       0
B    X     300
B    Y     250
C    X     220
C    Y       0
D    X       0
D    Y       0
```

Comment: Isn't there any more convenient way to define A, B, C, D data array (like using LEVEL and CONECT BY LEVEL for number arrays) instead of selecting them from DUAL?

Comment: @sbrbot - Yes, there is - but what does that have to do with your question? You said you know in advance what the values are. I assumed this means you have them in a table. Clearly they are not simply read from the data you posted, since it (the data you posted) may miss certain values altogether (such as 'D'). In any case, if you need to generate the table on the fly, you can do it in other ways. For example: `with table1 (key1) as (select column_value from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))), table2 (key2) as ...` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Get all possible combinations of Key1 and Key2 (you may store these or generate them with a Cartesian join), and left join that to an aggregate sum() query that is grouped by Key1 and Key2, coalescing the null sums to zero.